# Error opening terminal: xterm-256color

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vi, xterm, nano

When I try to *nano* something on my server I'm getting this error "Error opening terminal: xterm-256color." that I've never seen before, and on top of that *nano* used to work fine last week.  Even when I use *vi*, the file will open but I can't manipulate using normal *vi* commands.  When I press `i` to activate insert mode and then try to navigate the document, it just types an `A` or `B` or something.

The only thing that changed is I lost my private key and had to generate a new one, so I had to upload the new public key to my server. Anyone know why this is happening?

The server is running Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy.

---

**SOLUTION**

Open *Terminal*, select from the menu *Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Advanced* and under *Emulation* select "Declare terminal as: xterm-color not xterm-256color"

Reference: http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/mac-os-x-lion-terminal-color-remote-access-problem-fix/

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal's default $TERM value is xterm-256color. (Prior to Lion it was xterm-color.) If you're connecting to a remote host that doesn't have the necessary terminfo files installed, I recommend you install them. Selecting xterm-color is a workaround, but disables some important enhancements that are new in Lion Terminal. At the very least, you should try using xterm instead of xterm-color to see how that works for you, because xterm-color represents an older branch of xterm that isn't as capable as modern xterm.

Comment: how do we go about installing the necessary terminfo files then?

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question. (For the record, I'm unfamiliar with your system and don't know the answer for your situation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably due to a Lion upgrade/install. Did you do that recently @Gih?

Possible duplicate (with fix) at 
[nano error: Error opening terminal: xterm-256color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804208/nano-error-error-opening-terminal-xterm-256color)

EDIT:

Easiest fix (takes 10 seconds)...from [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562423/michael):

> There is a solution much easier:
>   http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/mac-os-x-lion-terminal-color-remote-access-problem-fix/

Comment: Worked :-), follow this link for the simplest solution http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/mac-os-x-lion-terminal-color-remote-access-problem-fix/, or follow the link in the answer for other options, ill leave this question open as i couldn't find the other one in my search so this might help

Comment: Note that this is a workaround, but may leave your computer in an undesirable state, because it's (apparently) missing some terminfo files. xterm-color represents an older branch of xterm with less functionality and is not recommended. You might also try "xterm" to see how that works for you, since it's overall a better representation of Lion Terminal's capabilities than is xterm-color. Fixing the problem requires installing the missing terminfo files. If the problem is occurring when connected to a remote host, then the terminfo files must be installed on that host, not your local Mac.

Answer (score 10):

xterm-256color is a reference to a terminfo entry. It should be in /usr/share/terminfo/x/.
I believe in ubuntu, the package containing the file is ncurses-term.

If the file is corrupted or missing reinstalling the package should fix it. You can also take a look at the files /usr/share/terminfo and set your TERM variable to a supported emulation by your server (xterm is usually a good choice).

About why this happend, the file may be corrupted or missing (check your filesystem), but i think the most likely reason is you changed your terminal emulator or its settings.

Comment: thanks, do you have any resource on how to reinstall the package or setting the TERM variable?  Ill give that a try

Comment: The [ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html)  have a section about [package management](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/package-management.html). TERM is an environment variable, is set by the shell,  the default shell in Ubuntu is bash, you can find a guide to it [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: sudo apt-get install ncurses-term

Comment: In case you cannot find term-256color after installing ncurses-term then try gnome-256color and check it again with "tput color"

Answer (score 3):

Snow Leopard doesn't have the xterm-256color terminfo file in /usr/share/terminfo/78. A Lion upgrade will add it. An Xcode 3 to 4 upgrade will delete it (as well as 90% of the other terminfo files in /usr/share/terminfo/78 ).  Time Machine backups in my case [confirmed](http://www.unityisplural.com/2011/09/macos-x-lion-xcode-4-madness.html) this peculiar chain of events.

If you use Time Machine you can restore the file. Set Finder to see UNIX files (at a command line, defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles True; killall Finder) or you won't be able to get to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can first try typing : `export TERM=xterm`
If it did not work then you can try :

> `export TERM=linux`

It works even in kernel with virgin system.