# nano error: Error opening terminal: xterm-256color

Tags: terminal, nano

After the installation of OSX Lion, I tried to:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

But I get this error:

```
Error opening terminal: xterm-256color
```

If I try to switch terminal.app preferences to open terminal windows in "xterm color" instead of `xterm-256color` everything works fine.

What's happening?

Comment: You might be missing some step here - like you ssh'ed from the Mac into some Debian or Ubuntu system, right? At least I hope you didn't try to edit /etc/apt/sources.list in a MacOS System... :)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

On Red Hat this worked for me:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

further info here: http://www.cloudfarm.it/fix-error-opening-terminal-xterm-256color-unknown-terminal-type/

Comment: Worked for me when ran on the remove system. Connection from was OS X -> Ubuntu

Comment: Interestingly, I had this error in a chroot-ed environment that has only minimal programs so far. I assume that there is some program missing that causes this, but unfortunately nano does not give more information as to why it exactly fails.

Comment: Works also when trying to use top inside a minikube local kubernetes system running as a VM based on buildroot inside Virtualbox on Max OS X. (which is ssh from MacOS into a Buildroot based VM and tgen run top)

Comment: The same solution seems correct for different systems, including Ubuntu/Debian and OSX (the OP's). How is this irrelevant?

Comment: This worked for me on a Debian system. How do I make this permanent? Such as having it occur when I log in via SSH?

Comment: While this may work (and even more generically than the "real" solutions) it's conceptually a workaround at best. You're essentially lying to your shell about the terminal you use to connect.

Comment: It might be a "hack" that sheds light in the underlying issue.

Comment: This worked for me when ccmake, instead of nano, was issuing the same error message

Comment: This hack also works on QNAP NAS after installing iotop qpkg to the BSD OS

Answer (score 30):

> After upgrading to OSX Lion, I started getting this error on certain (Debian/Ubuntu) servers. The fix is simply to install the “ncurses-term” package which provides the file /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color.

This worked for me on a Ubuntu server, via [Erik Osterman](http://www.osterman.com/wordpress/2011/07/20/xterm256color-unknown-terminal-type).

Answer (score 22):

I can confirm this is a terminfo issue. This is what worked for me. SSH in to the remote machine and run

```
 sudo apt-get install ncurses-term
```

Boom. Problem solved.

Comment: I think this may be one reason why nano may sometimes fail - e. g. if the problem happens at ncurses/terminfo instead.

Answer (score 8):

1. edit your `.bash_profile` file

   `vim .bash_profile`
2. commnet

   `#export TERM=xterm-256color`
3. add this

   `export TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo`

   `export TERM=xterm-basic`

   to your `.bash_profile`
4. finally

   run:

   `source .bash_profile`

Answer (score 6):

I, too, have this problem on an older Mac that I upgraded to Lion.

Before reading the terminfo tip, I was able to get vi and less working by doing "export TERM=xterm".

After reading the tip, I grabbed `/usr/share/terminfo` from a newer Mac that has fresh install of Lion and does not exhibit this problem.

Now, even though `echo $TERM` still yields `xterm-256color`, vi and less now work fine.

Comment: For anyone trying to get a chroot running on macOS, this fixes "Error opening terminal: " issue inside the chroot.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem connecting to http://sdf.org through Mac OS X Lion. I changed under `Terminal Preferences` (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) `> Advanced` pane, `Declare Terminal as` to `VT-100`.

I also marked `Delete Sends Ctrl-H` because this Mac connection was confusing `zsh`.

It appears to be working for my use case.

Comment: Thanks for an answer that did NOT involve changing the server!

Comment: This does not work for me. I connect from a Mac in Mavericks to a Mac in Snow Leopard. I get the error when I launch `top`.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Ah ok Nicolas, sorry but I'm no longer using Mac so I can't test this with you.

Answer (score 3):

somehow and sometimes "terminfo" folder comes corrupted after a fresh installation.
i don't know why, but the problem can be solved in this way:

```
1. Download Lion Installer from the App Store
2. Download unpkg: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16357/unpkg
3. Open Lion Installer app in Finder (Right click -> Show Package
Contents)
4. Open InstallESD.dmg (under SharedSupport)
5. Unpack BSD.pkg with unpkg (Located under Packages)   Term info
will be located in the new BSD folder in /usr/share/terminfo
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I encountered the same error and tried your suggested steps. I encountered a number of permission denied errors while unpacking with unpkg. The BSD folder appeared on my desktop, and I ran "sudo mv ~/Desktop/BSD/usr/share/terminfo /usr/share/terminfo" then restarted terminal, but I still get the same "Error opening terminal: xterm-256color" error.

Comment: maybe you can try this http://www.sendspace.com/file/hc2dus it's my terminfo folder. after replacing it, don't forget to chmod 555 /usr/share/terminfo

Answer (score 1):

Mine was quite a unique case but this could help someone. On Android I tried to copy nano from my termux binary folder to /system/xbin. Placed all the library dependencies in /system/lib and got this error. The libncurses.so.6 file I copied from termux had it's TERMINFO file still pointed to /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/terminfo

View pointed path with command

strings path-to-libncurses.so | grep /terminfo

To fix either make the termux terminfo dir and subdirs readable and executable by the nano user or copy the terminfo folder somewhere else and use a hexeditor to modify the plain text path in the shared library file.

Link to zipped terminfo folder
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m1tfHgkGRehBGh1jPMK4EaTgQb9EyCG7/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I ran to a similar situation when uding a chroot ssh configuration. And I fixed it as @Fortune has menstioned. find and copy terminfo folders to the chroot folder structure

Answer (score 0):

I hear that this can be fixed by overwriting your `/usr/share/terminfo` with one from the computer of somebody with a working install of Lion. I can't confirm whether this works or not, and unfortunately I haven't upgraded yet, so I can't provide you with that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in your .bashrc

```
if [ "$TERM" = xterm ]; then TERM=xterm-256color; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on linux mint, based on the link provided by @Meetai.com.
Put this in `.bashrc` and restart the terminal:

TERM="xterm"
export TERM

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem when ssh into another computer.  Setting TERM after logging in worked for me.  Apparently ssh will pass the TERM environment variable to the new terminal.

export TERM=xterm